# How do I "scale" a Flutter app so that it supports multiple users?

Tags: rest, flutter, authentication, restful-authentication, multi-user

I come from a web dev background and I got into Flutter a couple months ago (last year) it's awesome. I like developing multi-platform apps with Flutter or even React Native.

The thing is, I haven't really made a production app. And I guess this is the time!

--

So, we have a RestFul API in place. You make login POST requests to the server in JSON, that are vaguely like this.

```
{
    "user": string,
    "password": string,
    "uuid": string
}
```

This is fairly easy to do with flutter and the `http` package.

The app has been storing the user data from the login JSON request body with the `flutter_secure_storage`package under static key names.

The app is protected by **a code screen** that uses the `local_auth` package to use biometrics, if the user requests it. Code is mandatory, biometric auth is not. The logic behind this screens, is, if the user authenticates successfully, it just calls the login function, and passes the data to the function.

Now, the thing is, we've updated our system's way of working and you might need to use more than one account, which was previously possible with the solution I just gave you.

Now, would an encrypted SQLite db serve me well? What are the best practices around this?
I thought about checking values on the `flutter_secure_storage` and just adding a number in front, but that probably won't be as "scalable" as I want it to be.

**Keep in mind that the app is going to be storing user sensitive data, such as passwords and tokens.**

I've looked into flavors, but I don't think this requires a solution like that.

--

**What would you do?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A personal recommendation I would give you is the flutter package Hive. It’s encrypted by standard and has pretty fast read and write speeds. It can also generate adapters so you can store full class data without having to encode your data to a data string. However, if you only want to store very small keys and values secure storage will do.

I guess you could use the user ID or some user identifier as key and have an array with the different sort of authentication as data, if you have any follow up questions comment thing below!

Comment: Thanks! I've heard of hive but never knew it was a flutter package. I was kinda stuck because I wanted to store classes in secure storage but I think it only allows for strings.
This makes it so much easier. By the way, what do you think of calling the login function on code or biometrics auth and passing data kinda like `login(user, pass, uuid)`? I am trying to learn good practices in dart/flutter. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you mean the data you send to login? The only thing I’m not sure about is the plain password over request, but I guess if it’s encoded there’s no problem. As long as you don’t store the passwords on a server and just locally it seems fine to me